# FOS User Bundle vs Symfony 3 Native Implementation of User Authorization/Management

Tags: php, authorization, symfony, fosuserbundle

Symfony framework has a "remarkable" implementation of user authorization and management using a 3rd party bundle - FOS User Bundle.

However, Symfony 3 also have the security component (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security.html) that have enough of functionality to implement a complete system without FOS.

What plan would you follow to implement a complete user authorization and management system without FOS or other 3rd party bundles? Required functionality: registration, sign in, user roles, privileges.

Would you even go this route or using FOS is the better way? Why does Symfony not have a solid out of box solution for user management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say Symfony doesn't have a standard implementation because FosUser was already out and good enough  when they would have started to make their own.

As far as using Fos or not, this is a perfect example of "Reinventing the wheel" as FosUser is the most used Symfony bundle and nobody complains about it(except for the fact that they still didn't release a stable 2.0 for Symfony 3).

If you still want to make you own implementation the best source you can find to bootstrap your project would obviously be FOSUser.

If you want to have a look at another UserBundle unrelated to fos you can check out: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/tree/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/UserBundle